# Recognizing edges based on points and normals

Tags: algorithm, matlab, pattern-matching, computational-geometry

I have a bit of a problem categorizing points based on relative normals.
What I would like to do is use the information I got below to fit a simplified polygon to the points, with a bias towards 90 degree angles to an extent.

I have the rough (although not very accurate) normal lines for each point, but I'm not sure how to separate the data base on closeness of points and closeness of the normals. I plan to do a linear regression after chunking the points for each face, as the normal lines sometimes does not fit well with the actual faces (although they are close to each other for each face)

**Example:**
[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img842/8439/ptnormals.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img842/8439/ptnormals.png)

Ideally, I would like to be able to fit a rectangle around this data. However, the polygon does not need to be convex, nor does it have to be aligned with the axis.

Any hints as to how to achieve something like this would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea of the "official way" things like this are solved, but wouldn't "measuring" the angles between 3 consecutive points and finding the ones closest to 90 deg., give you the edge points (the one in the middle) ?

Comment: An interesting example, btw. I like it.

Comment: Sometimes though, there's some noise, and you may have one point that is at a 90 degree angle between two other points, but would be normally fit into a straight line :\

Comment: Oh, well, as I said, I don't know the "official" way. I didn't remmeber that. But, still, if you're always fitting a rectangle, you can always pick the farthest of the points as the right ones (4 points as a result - if you get one of the noise ones as a result, that one won't "survive" that criteria).

Comment: Rectangle is convex! So use convex hull and then rectangle it :)

Comment: I probably shoulda been more more specific, but what I am doing is fitting planes to lidar data of roofs. They aren't always rectangular, but a lot of the angles are close to 90 degrees.

Comment: @Draskosha, Haha, yeah I thought about doing a convex hull, but the problem is it's not necessarily convex. I might be dealing with some L shape things, which will screw up convex hulls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try the following

1. Cluster the points based on proximity and similar angle. I'd use single-linkage hierarchical clustering ([LINKAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/linkage.html) in Matlab), since you don't know *a priori* how many edges there will be. Single linkage favors linear structures, which is exactly what you're looking for. As the distance criterion between two points you can use the euclidean distance between point coordinates multiplied by a function of the angle that increases very steeply as soon as the angle differs more than, say, 20 or 30 degrees.
2. Do (robust) linear regression into the data. Using the normals may or may not help. My guess is that they won't help too much. For simplicity, you may want to disregard the normals initially.
3. Find the intersections between the lines.
4. If you have to, you can always try and improve the fit, for example by constraining opposite lines to be parallel.

If that fails, you could try and implement the approach in [THIS PAPER](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=279014), which allows fitting multiple straight lines at once.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I'm looking for. I'm out of time working in the lab on sunday, but I'll try it tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here's my attempt at solving the problem as I understood it:

I am using the angles of the normal vectors to find points belonging to each side of the rectangle (left, right, up, down), then simply fit a line to each.

```
%# create random data (replace those with your actual data)
num = randi([10 20]);
pT = zeros(num,2);
pT(:,1) = rand(num,1);
pT(:,2) = ones(num,1) + 0.01*randn(num,1);
aT = 90 + 10*randn(num,1);

num = randi([10 20]);
pB = zeros(num,2);
pB(:,1) = rand(num,1);
pB(:,2) = zeros(num,1) + 0.01*randn(num,1);
aB = 270 + 10*randn(num,1);

num = randi([10 20]);
pR = zeros(num,2);
pR(:,1) = ones(num,1) + 0.01*randn(num,1);
pR(:,2) = rand(num,1);
aR = 0 + 10*randn(num,1);

num = randi([10 20]);
pL = zeros(num,2);
pL(:,1) = zeros(num,1) + 0.01*randn(num,1);
pL(:,2) = rand(num,1);
aL = 180 + 10*randn(num,1);

pts = [pT;pR;pB;pL];                 %# x/y coords
angle = mod([aT;aR;aB;aL],360);      %# angle in degrees [0,360]

%# plot points and normals
plot(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), 'o'), hold on
theta = angle * pi / 180;
quiver(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), cos(theta), sin(theta), 0.4, 'Color','g')
hold off

%# divide points based on angle
[~,bin] = histc(angle,[0 45 135 225 315 360]);
bin(bin==5) = 1;                     %# combine last and first bin

%# fit line to each segment
hold on
for i=1:4
    %# indices of points in this segment
    idx = ( bin == i );

    %# x/y or y/x
    if i==2||i==4, xx=1; yy=2; else xx=2; yy=1; end

    %# fit line
    coeff = polyfit(pts(idx,xx), pts(idx,yy), 1);
    fit(:,1) = 0:0.05:1;
    fit(:,2) = polyval(coeff, fit(:,1));

    %# plot fitted line
    plot(fit(:,xx), fit(:,yy), 'Color','r', 'LineWidth',2)
end
hold off
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amro. I'm not sure if I described it well enough, but my data isn't really limited to rectangles, nor are they very well behaved.

Comment: @Xzhsh: the solution above wasn't really about fitting a rectangle, more like 4 line segments, where each is determined by points with a certain direction of the normals.. Perhaps you should describe exactly what results are you expecting; based on the figure you posted, the points almost form a rectangle.

Comment: Based on the figure I posted, I was indeed trying to get a rectangle, but I was probably not clear on the nature of my data. Since it's lidar data of roofs, I could be getting triangles, octogons, or just any kind of polygon. I can't really restrict the set of results to that of a quadrilateral  :\. That said, some of the line fitting in your answer really did help me (I was stuck on fitting a vertical line when I had one), so thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the mean value for the X and Y coordinates for each side and then just make lines based on that.